# Useful Java Coding Tools

Tags: java

I was wondering what kind of tools people use to make their coding experience more enjoyable or easy.  Especially in java.

Also, what kind of tools would be nice?

EDIT: Let's assume we all use some IDE that supports plugins... :-p

Comment: I personally use Eclipse and svn.  What I want is some code that can analyze the code that I've already written and my comments (which I believe are rather excellent) and generate interfaces based on comments

Comment: Have you considered annotations and an annotation processing tool?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what they are.  I'll look into them. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210755/java-must-have-development-tools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. An IDE like IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans. If you use IntelliJ, get addicted to `Ctrl+Space` and `Alt+Enter`
2. Use debugger
3. Use IDE built-in profiler or plugins like YourKit
4. Build and continuous integration tool, ant, maven, buildr, TeamCity, Hudson, etc
5. Java Coffee at `CAFE BABE`

Comment: One more thing I want to add is a good error & warning tool like Lint4j :-)

Comment: +1 for continuous integration

Comment: One more : JUnit. Unit testing is must for a developer.

Comment: One more and important is Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V :-)

Comment: LOL no, copy + paste is a design flaw: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming

Comment: Actually, when I copy paste, it is usually a loop, which ends up being significantly different to the original.  Identical copy pasting may be a designer's flaw

Answer (score 5):

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) is a nice tool and there are plugins for many IDE's.

Answer (score 3):

well, primarily an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) such as [eclipse](http://eclipse.org/), [intelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/)

a code repository is also very useful ([CVS](http://savannah.nongnu.org/project/memberlist.php?detailed=1&group=cvs) or [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/))

Answer (score 3):

I like using the Eclipse [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org) plugin to calculate my JUnit code coverage every time I run my tests.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse, Maven, Google Collections, Apache Commons, YourKit, and a 30" monitor!

Comment: A friend mentioned maven the other day.  I'm going to have to check it out.

Comment: +1 for the 30'' monitor!!!! LOL

Comment: Google guava is the new google collection

Answer (score 2):

- **Netbeans IDE**: the profiler and debugger are phenomenal.  If you are unlucky enough to design GUIs in Swing, the GUI builder is excellent too.
- **TortoiseSVN or Subclipse plugin for Eclipse** -- Faster and much less painful than using command line for Subversion.
- **Notepad++** (windows only): for quick viewing of source, and working with XML/HTML and so forth.  If you aren't on doze, use the platform equivalent.
- **Espresso and quality port.**  The first is for when you can't figure out a tough problem.  The second is to make grueling, awful parts of coding bearable.  Yes, the alcoholic kind of port.  Find your [Ballmer Peak!](http://xkcd.com/323/)
- Edit: **[Google code](http://code.google.com/)**: Search for similar projects, and see how other people implemented something tricky.  Especially useful if you're having trouble figuring out how to implement an algorithm elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

All of the major IDEs others have suggested have great plugins for version control, building, and unit testing.

Use your debugger!

**IntelliJ IDEA** with it's awesome editing and the [Key Promoter Plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1003) make Java editing very smooth.

Check out command-line tools like javap. Good luck!

Comment: +1 for IntelliJ IDEA. And it's OpneSource now!

Answer (score 1):

I saw a good list but I wanna add one more b'coz it helped me a lot and made my programming better. Hats off to [google](http://www.google.com)

:-)

Answer (score 1):

[CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to enforce coding standard, 
[Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) for checking code coverage.

On a related note also check the book 
[Java Power Tools](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527938)
which covers around 30 open source tools that help to do better development with Java

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the project one time saver could be: [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) ( formely known as Java Rebel )  which allows you to reload classes dynamically without having to restart your VM.

Looks pretty awesome.

Here's a video: [JRabel in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JGGFCzspaY)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java), it's an innovative code exploration plugin for Eclipse.  The tool includes:

- Code visualization - interactive graphical representation of components and associations.
- Code navigation - unique navigation view shows all the associations and works with you while you write or read code.
- Quick search - search as you type for methods, fields, file, etc.